# UML de Clases para representar colección que contiene otras dos clases

Tags: diseño-de-clases, uml

Estoy realizando un diagrama UML de clases y quiero plasmas en este una relación de la clase **A** con las clases **B** y **C** ambas representadas por la misma variable "**ambas**" en **A**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Diagrama de ejemplo con PlantUML](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/png/SoWkIImgAStDuKhEIImkLd2ivkAgvU9oKh3HrLLmLB1IICnDIYo6IZf199snIZg39HrIyrA0fW40)

Se puede considerar como que en la clase **A** quiero almacenar en la variable de instancia **ambas** variables que pueden ser instancias de **B** y/o **C** (como si fuera true y false pero estas son objetos de clases diferentes)

Answer (score 0):

No he podido confirmar que sea para todos los casos que se tenga una colección de ese tipo.

Analizando mas el problema al tener dicha colección uno va a esperar que los objetos de ambas clases (**B** y **C**) respondan a los mismos mensajes (protocolo). Por ello estas clases pueden extender de otra clase o implementar una interfaz (**D**) para que la clase **A** tenga una colección de esa clase o interfaz (**D**).

Ej.:

La clase **A** tiene una colección (**ambas**) de **D**.
Las clases **B** y **C** extiende a **D** y respetan su protocolo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Diagrama de ejemplo](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/png/SoWkIImgAStDuN9HKD9IKh3HrLLmLB1IICnDIYpcIiv9B2vMSEHAJ2ekAKfCBb602BXm0LNRr02LEa6LEC44d242GDeXDIy5Q2u0)

Espero que ayude a alquilen con la misma inquietud.